# Texts oveflows of div in iPad - google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, ipad

I have a RTL website. My texts overflows the div dimensions independent of div size. I just face this problem in google chrome when using iPad. The last line in the image below is out of div box (not aligned with red title which has 100% width)
[image]

Is this a bug? Can I solve it by any CSS or any other tricks?

Here is the asp-html code:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="redTitles">
        <h1><%=rs("title")%></h1>
     </div>
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <div style="text-align:justify">
        <%=rs("body")%>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

and here is the live version:
http://www.zingapp.ir/content/?id=1

Comment: Can you post some code snippets for debugging purposes?

Comment: I added the code in to the question. and the live link too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `@media only screen` so that when you are using it on your iPad, it will resize.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    // code here.
}
```